# Hosted web platform for a small database application (back- and front-end)

Tags: web-apps, database

I'm looking for a **hosted database solution** that allows you to define both the back-end (tables, views, relationships) as well as the front-end (forms, reports, ...).

Both the **number of tables** as well as the **record count** is pretty low: about 15 tables and less than 10.000 records in total (for all tables).

The focus is on **data presentation**: the data itself will hardly change, so I don't mind doing that in the back-end. But I need the presentation layer to be flexible enough to handle things such as:

- crosstabs (pivot tables)
- conditional formatting
- charting

#### My requirements:

- A fully hosted solution
- No coding, other than some minor JS, HTML or CSS hacking
- Mature database back-end (i.e. not trying to hide this from the designer)
- Import data (e.g. from CSV) and bulk updates
- Customizable front-end
- Extensive charting features
- Notification features (send out mail if certain criteria are met)
- Good customer support

#### Bonus points for:

- An API in order to integrate with other web platforms

#### My background:

I have an extensive RDBMS background (Oracle, SQL Server) as well as programming (Java, Python, ...) but I don't have the time nor the resources to set this up myself.

#### Past experiences:

I've already tried the following vendors:

- [Intuit Quickbase](http://quickbase.intuit.com)
- [Caspio](https://www.caspio.com)
- [Knack](https://www.knackhq.com)
- [TrackVia](http://www.trackvia.com)
- [Zoho](http://www.zoho.com)

Each of them failed for one or more reasons. The best back-end and customizable front-end was **Caspio**, but they have very poor charting features. Also, as you write small components (called *datapages*), you still need to create the *glue* between them (i.e. the actual application) and host that somewhere. Caspio could've made the cut, but they asked a four-figure amount for setting up 3 database triggers, which I found rather preposterous.

**QuickBase** was easy to set-up, but has a very backward way of dealing with table relationships. Also, charting abilities are still lacking in some areas and the notification functionality is crippled.

**TrackVia** tries too hard to shield the user from the back-end, and I had nothing but issues while testing out **Knack**, so that trial came to an early end.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have experience with SQL Server, I'd recommend that you look at LightSwitch. You can easily [host the applications and DB up on Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg481774.aspx).

For the charting/reporting you can look at [hosting SSRS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj992719.aspx) in Azure, which should cover your needs and then some, or using an external JavaScript library if you don't need pixel-perfect reporting (such as [d3.js](http://d3js.org/), etc.). Another option, since it'd be a SQL server on the back-end would be connecting Excel directly to the database using something like PowerPivot and normal Excel voodoo to analyze the data.

As a bonus, with the release of Visual Studio Community (which is basically Visual Studio Pro for individuals and teams of 5 or fewer people), you can do all of the development for free. You'd just need to follow the instructions [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160112222819/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2014/11/12/develop-lightswitch-and-cloud-business-apps-using-visual-studio-community-2013.aspx) to get both Visual Studio and LightSwitch.

**As an update - Microsoft has deprecated LightSwitch in favor of their Power Apps platform.**

Comment: Thanks @Nathan, very interesting suggestion. I'm currently giving Knack another go, which is going better than it did the first time, but this is quite a comprehensive alternative.